# Unable to Edit the Material UI Textfields in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React ,
I tried to design a form using material UI in React. 
I was able to design the form with textfields but unable to edit the data if i use value attribute to the textfield.
And how can i call a parent function when onChange function is called for Textfield which is there in child component.Here is my Code.

In the parent Component i am including like this

```
 render() {
const { name, email, mobileNumber } = this.state.serviceRequest;

return (
  <div>
  <HomeTemplate 
  handleShow = {this.handleShow}
  handleClose = {this.handleClose}
  name = {name}
  email ={email}
  mobileNumber = {mobileNumber}
  DateFnsUtils ={DateFnsUtils}
  handleDateChange ={this.handleDateChange}
  handleChange = {this.handleChange}
   /> 
 </div>
  );
```

}

In the child component i am having Text field like this. due to unable to post the whole code i am posting part of the code which is useful to get the problem. 
I will post paste bin link in comments also.

```
 <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="emailId"
            label="Email Address"
            type="email"
            value= {props.email}
            fullWidth
          />
```

Please suggest me how can i do this?

Comment: Paste bin links are ==> https://pastebin.com/NssJg1dW , https://pastebin.com/U8thJtqZ

Answer (score 5):

You can send a function of Parent as a `prop` to the Child and set that as `onChange` prop of `TextField`.

For example, let's say your Child component looks like this:

```
function Demo(props) {
  return (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      id="standard-name"
      label="Name"
      value={props.name}              // it gets value from prop
      onChange={props.onNameChange}   // it gets handler function from prop too!
      margin="normal"
    />
  );
}
```

Now your parent component is responsible to send both `props.name` and `props.onNameChange`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Sleepy cat"
  };

  handleNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <Demo 
          onNameChange={this.handleNameChange}  // send a function as prop, that will change the state in parent
          name={this.state.name}                // send the state of parent to child
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the full demo:

```js
const {TextField} = window['material-ui'];

function Demo(props) {
  return (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      id="standard-name"
      label="Name"
      value={props.name}
      onChange={props.onNameChange}
      margin="normal"
    />
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Sleepy cat"
  };

  handleNameChange = event => {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <code>{"Parent State: " + JSON.stringify(this.state)}</code>
        <Demo onNameChange={this.handleNameChange} name={this.state.name} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@3.9.2/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is a common need a developer requires when building application using react.

You want the child component to the reflect the changing data when calling `onChange`event.

Note, the child component can have its own state but in case there are several components that need to reflect the same changing data you can lift the *state up* to the *closest ancestor*.

@mehamasun has already illustrated how to do that in his example.

> Parent(state) -> Child(props) -> //Event called -> Parent(state changed via event handler) -> rerender Child(props)